# how to use time.sleep to affect part of the codes?

Tags: python, time, sleep, telethon, event-loop

I want to send messages at different times to another channel. For example, I want to send 10 messages at once from my channel to another channel with 30 minutes intervals.

I tried using `time.sleep()`, but it also affects other coroutines, which I don't want.

I tried using `asyncio.sleep()` but it sleeps when they are sent (not between them).

I have 3 different output and input channels:

```
#a function to delay and then send message
async def myfunc(...)
    time.sleep(x) #delay x second
    await client.send_message(outputt, event.message) #send to output

#an event loop with three client
#when new messages arrived from input channel send them to functions
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input))
async def event_handler(event):
    await myfunc(...)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input))
async def event_handler(event):
    await myfunc(...)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input))
async def event_handler(event):
    await myfunc(...)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: async was bolted onto python relatively recently. Many python functions should not be sued in an async function and `time.sleep` is one of them. Use `await asyncio.sleep(x)` instead.

Comment: None of those event handlers will complete until your delay is done.

Comment: @tdelaney 
asyncio.sleep() sleep at the first of sending each messages not between messages! for example sending first message at 01:00:00 pm and second at 01:00:10 with await asyncio.sleep(60) the result will 01:01:00 and 01:01:10 but I want to be 01:01:00 and 01:02:00

Comment: @amir, thanks for the comments! One immediate problem is that you are using ```time.sleep``` instead of ```await asyncio.sleep```. But you said after this you still have a problem; "I tried using asyncio.sleep() but it sleeps when they are sent (not between them).". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What you described with 10 instead of 60 probably means you have two sleeps - one before a loop and one during a loop -- and you only changed one of them.  You aren't showing us your real code, so we can't really do very much.

Comment: @SimplyDev tnx for your comments :) when using `await asyncio.sleep` for example we receive 2 message in one of the channels. first at 1:00:00 pm and second at 1:00:02 pm, ok?! and we set 60 sec delay! so the first message send to output channel at 1:01:00 and the second at 1:01:02. we have only 2 second delay between two message! 
I want 60 sec delay between two message. send the first - delay 60 sec - and send next , ...